# Tkinter Image icon not working or aligning properly in a Labelframe

Tags: python, tkinter

This question concerns Python's Tkinter.

I first produced this GUI, a simple two-column set of rows in a Labelframe, with an icon on the right:

[image]

The above behaviour was correct and expected, based on this following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

icon_colours_fp = r"D:\Dropbox\coding\python\experiments\icon_component.gif"
icon_col = tk.PhotoImage(file=icon_colours_fp)
# icon_col = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(icon_colours_fp))

tk.Label(root, text="Past").grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Label(root, text="Today").grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Label(root, text="Future").grid(row=2, column=0)

_b = ttk.Button(root, image=icon_col)
_b['image'] =icon_col
_b.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I then re-wrote the code as a class, hoping to produce something similar within a Labelframe:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Options(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        super().__init__()

        main_labelframe = ttk.LabelFrame(parent, text="Test Labelframe")
        main_labelframe.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        frame_1 = tk.Frame(main_labelframe)
        frame_1_sep = ttk.Separator(main_labelframe, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        frame_2 = tk.Frame(main_labelframe)

        frame_1.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        frame_1_sep.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH)
        frame_2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        tk.Label(frame_1, text="Past").grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Label(frame_1, text="Today").grid(row=1)
        tk.Label(frame_1, text="Future").grid(row=2)

        icon_colours_fp = r"D:\Dropbox\coding\python\experiments\icon_component.gif"
        icon_col = tk.PhotoImage(file=icon_colours_fp)
        _b = ttk.Button(frame_2, image=icon_col)
        _b['image'] = icon_col
        _b.grid(row=0, column=0)


class Gui(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        options = Options(self)
        options.pack()


gui = Gui()
gui.mainloop()
```

The code then failed, in two respects:

1. The icon fails to appear.
2. The ttk Button becomes misaligned. (It appears in the centre, whereas by the grid, it should appear at the top.)

The failed code appears as follows:

[image]

I have experimented: among others, I changed the geometry manager to `.pack()`, and changed the parent of `ttk.Button`, but without success. Would appreciate some pointers as to where I've gone wrong, especially as to the disappearing icon.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't keep a reference to the image. Easiest way here is to change:

```
icon_col = tk.PhotoImage(file=icon_colours_fp)
b = ttk.Button(frame_2, image=icon_col)
_b['image'] = icon_col
```

To:

```
self.icon_col = tk.PhotoImage(file=icon_colours_fp)
b = ttk.Button(frame_2, image=self.icon_col)
```

Comment: The icon now works! Thank you. I thought the `_b['image'] = icon_col` was an adequate enough reference to the image. Also, what is causing the misalignment issue, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: You should have done `b.image = icon_col` rather than `b['image']`